# Fixup commits are not squashed

Tags: git

I've discovered Git's `fixup`/`autosquash` feature and want to give it a try. Unfortunately, I'm having issues with squashing some `fixup` commits.

This is my current Git history when running `git log --oneline -n 4`:

```
95686a33 (HEAD -> feature/ABC-1234-My-Feature, origin/feature/ABC-1234-My-Feature) fixup! feat: implement my feature
ac56a2ee fixup! feat: implement my feature
de904aa3 fixup! feat: implement my feature
cc3a205b feat: implement my feature
```

Now I'm running `git rebase -i --autosquash cc3a205b` and the editor opens with the following content:

```
pick de904aa3 fixup! feat: implement my feature
pick ac56a2ee fixup! feat: implement my feature
pick 95686a33 fixup! feat: implement my feature

# Rebase cc3a205b..95686a33 onto cc3a205b (3 commands)
```

I'm closing the editor without changing anything, leading to the following output:

```
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/feature/ABC-1234-My-Feature.
```

When executing `git log --oneline -n 4` again, the 3 `fixup` commits are still present.

I expected the history to only contain the single commit `feat: implement my feature` with a new Git commit ID, but without the `fixup` commits.

Am I doing something wrong or do I have the wrong expectations?

Running `git --version` returns `git version 2.38.1.windows.1`, so I'm using the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your pick list does not contain the commit into which you want to merge your fixups:

```
pick de904aa3 fixup! feat: implement my feature
pick ac56a2ee fixup! feat: implement my feature
pick 95686a33 fixup! feat: implement my feature
```

Note that your `feat: implment my feature` commit doesn't show up there. Without that, Git cannot recognize these as fixup commits and there's nothing for them to merge into.

You need to rebase against `cc3a205b^` (the parent of `cc3a205b`) instead:

```
git rebase -i --autosquash cc3a205b^
```